# CXF and JBoss 6.4: Two Classes Have the same XML Type Name

Tags: web-services, jboss, cxf

I have an issue when deploying my CXF project to JBoss EAP 6.4 that does NOT seem to be covered by other people asking about this issue.

I am receiving the following stack trace when I attempt to deploy:

```
14:02:08,701 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 119) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AdminServices': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    (snip)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    (snip)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:329) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86) [cxf-core-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:470) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:696) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:530) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:263) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 208 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://app.application.com/adminServices}addCatalog". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

(sample)

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://app.application.com/adminServices}updateQuantityAllocationResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at com.jason.app.control.jaxws_asm.UpdateQuantityAllocationResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at com.jason.app.adminservices.UpdateQuantityAllocationResponse
    at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.jason.app.adminservices.ObjectFactory.createUpdateQuantityAllocationResponse(com.jason.app.adminservices.UpdateQuantityAllocationResponse)
    at com.jason.app.adminservices.ObjectFactory
```

I do NOT recognize the com.jason.app.control.jaxws_asm package, and it does not exist in the EAR file I am deploying. This implies to me that JBoss is doing something, but I have no idea what.

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml is simple, only excluding the built-in webservices subsystem since I am using a more modern version of CXF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>    <deployment>        <exclude-subsystems>            <subsystem name="webservices" />        </exclude-subsystems>   </deployment> </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am totally stumped on this issue. If anyone can help, I would appreciate. I will post more information if requested.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have this class defined:
*at com.jason.app.adminservices.UpdateQuantityAllocationResponse*

In your WS, you probably have a method that contains something like this:
@WebMethod //exposed as operation in your WS
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "***UpdateQuantityAllocation***") //this is the wrapper element in the response

CXF/JAXB generates this class:
*at com.jason.app.control.jaxws_asm.UpdateQuantityAllocation**Response***

Thus you end up with 2 classes having same name.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me, in my case, i copy-pasted the generated client classes from another project (for the same WS), but the package was different.
IDE automatically fixed the package from JAVA headers, but didn't changed the string in @ResponseWrapper attributes.